# Retrieve exception message from postgresql function

Tags: perl, postgresql, exception, dbi, catalyst

I have a trigger function on a table that runs on inserts which for certain circumstances will raise an exception.

I maintain an old Perl application running on Catalyst that creates a transaction and inserts rows on the table.

When the trigger function raises an exception, I'd like to be able to print out just the error message I throw and not any debugging information (database operation, context, perl file, etc).

So for example, if my function throws something like:

```
raise exception 'Item with id % cannot be shipped at this time.', new.id;
```

I would like to only see

> Item with id 13 cannot be shipped at this time.

and not

> DBIx::Class::Row::insert(): DBI Exception: DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR: Item with id 13 cannot be shipped at this time. [for Statement "INSERT INTO ... at /home/../lib/Class/Controller/Inv.pm line 260

The perl code is currently something like

```
$c->model('Class')->schema->txn_do(sub {
    ...
    eval {
        $shipment->insert;
        1;
    } or do {
        $error = $@;
        last;
    };

    if ($error) {
        $c->stash->{error} = $error;
    }
);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this substitution:

```
my $error = $@;
$error =~ s/^.*ERROR: (.*) \[for Statement.*$/$1/;
```

Comment: Yeah. I mean I thought about using a regex.  Thought there might've been a more... I guess 'proper' way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You could access the errstr() method of the database handle, which is what is what is passed to warn/die anyway

```
 warn $c->model('Class')->schema->storage->dbh->errstr();
```